# Understanding callback function differences

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

My code:

```
 checkIsMotoOrEcomerce: function(booAnim) {
    var objIsEcmOrMto = $('.isMotoOrEcm'),
            objEcom = objIsEcmOrMto.filter('[name="ecommerce"]'),
            objMoto = objIsEcmOrMto.filter('[name="moto"]'),
            objMotoBox = $('.motoBox'),
            objEcmBox = $('.apiIntegrationBox'),
            strBehaviorShow,
            strBehaviorHide,
            objMain = this;


    if (booAnim) {
        strBehaviorShow = 'slideDown';
        strBehaviorHide = 'slideUp';
    } else {
        strBehaviorShow = 'show';
        strBehaviorHide = 'hide';
    }
    if (objEcom.is(':checked')) {
        objEcmBox[strBehaviorShow](objMain.checkIsMotoOrEcmVisible());
    } else {
        objEcmBox[strBehaviorHide](objMain.checkIsMotoOrEcmVisible());
    }
    if (objMoto.is(':checked')) {
        objMotoBox[strBehaviorShow](objMain.checkIsMotoOrEcmVisible());
    } else {
        objMotoBox[strBehaviorHide](objMain.checkIsMotoOrEcmVisible());
    }        
},
checkIsMotoOrEcmVisible: function() {
    var objMotoBox = $('.motoBox'),
            objEcmBox = $('.apiIntegrationBox');

    if (objMotoBox.is(':visible') && !objEcmBox.is(':visible')) {
        console.log('moto');
    } else if (!objMotoBox.is(':visible') && objEcmBox.is(':visible')) {
        console.log('eccomerce');
    } else if (objMotoBox.is(':visible') && objEcmBox.is(':visible')) {
        console.log('both');
    } else {
        console.log('none');
    }
  }
```

I cannot understand why this is working on first run, but when I'm running second time then its returning error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function".

When I am using this code:

```
    if (objEcom.is(':checked')) {
        objEcmBox[strBehaviorShow](objMain.checkIsMotoOrEcmVisible);
    } else {
        objEcmBox[strBehaviorHide](objMain.checkIsMotoOrEcmVisible);
    }
    if (objMoto.is(':checked')) {
        objMotoBox[strBehaviorShow](objMain.checkIsMotoOrEcmVisible);
    } else {
        objMotoBox[strBehaviorHide](objMain.checkIsMotoOrEcmVisible);
    }
```

It not returning any errors but working only on first run.
Can you help me understand the differences between using `objMain.checkIsMotoOrEcmVisible()` and `objMain.checkIsMotoOrEcmVisible`

Why when I put function name instead calling object propety, everything seams to work?

```
    function blabla() {
        var objMotoBox = $('.motoBox'),
                objEcmBox = $('.apiIntegrationBox');

        if (objMotoBox.is(':visible') && !objEcmBox.is(':visible')) {
            console.log('moto');
        } else if (!objMotoBox.is(':visible') && objEcmBox.is(':visible')) {
            console.log('eccomerce');
        } else if (objMotoBox.is(':visible') && objEcmBox.is(':visible')) {
            console.log('both');
        } else {
            console.log('none');
        }
    }


    if (objEcom.is(':checked')) {
        objEcmBox[strBehaviorShow](blabla());
    } else {
        objEcmBox[strBehaviorHide](blabla());
    }
    if (objMoto.is(':checked')) {
        objMotoBox[strBehaviorShow](blabla());
    } else {
        objMotoBox[strBehaviorHide](blabla());
    }
```

Comment: `objMain.checkIsMotoOrEcmVisible` is a reference to the function. When you use this as a parameter to a function you are passing the function object.

`objMain.checkIsMotoOrEcmVisible()` calls the function. When you use this as a parameter to a function you are passing the _return value_ of the function.

What exactly is the result you are expecting from the latter code? Is objMotoBox a dictionary of functors, if not, I do not see how this could work?

Comment: Thank you, I understand differences between calling `objMain.checkIsMotoOrEcmVisible` and `objMain.checkIsMotoOrEcmVisible()`. This code suppose to execute callback function after slide animation will done. Somehow its working in case when I'm using `objEcmBox['show'](objMain.checkIsMotoOrEcmVisible);` but it's not working for `objEcmBox['slideDown'](objMain.checkIsMotoOrEcmVisible);`

Comment: Ah ok! sorry. I would hazard a guess that `slideDown` in `objEcmBox` doesn't exist, check that it is getting set when it is meant to, could just be an if statement that has the wrong conditions so it's passing over it :)

Comment: hmmm, but sliding animation working fine, only problem is that its not executing callback after animation is done